# abrir un Activity desde otro Activity

Tags: android-studio

Buen día a todos
desarrollo una app en Android studio
pero tengo un problema al abrir un activity y es que cuando toco a un boton, se supone que me mandaría a otra pantalla sin embargo cuando hago eso, la app se cierra, he seguido los pasos que he visto en youtube pero no me funciona...

este es el activity principal que llama a otra que se llama searchtabs

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


Button btnLogin;
EditText txtUser, txtPass;

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),searchtabs.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
    txtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInicio);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

 }
}
```

y esta es el activity que debería ejecutarse

```
public class searchtabs extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchtabs);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbarid);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Añadiendo fragments
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentBuscar(), "Buscar");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentPromo(), "Promociones");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentPerfil(), "Perfil");
    // adaptador
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
 }
}
```

si me olvido de algo se los agradezco, gracias.

Comment: Revisa los mensajes de error del 'logcat' seguro hay mas información alli acerca del error que está cerrando la aplicación.

Comment: me sale esto de los tantos errores, 
07-22 23:54:33.985 27751-27751/peru.viajar.app.com.viajarperu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: peru.viajar.app.com.viajarperu, PID: 27751
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {peru.viajar.app.com.viajarperu/peru.viajar.app.com.viajarperu.searchtabs}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Dice que tu activity `searchtabs` no ha sido declarada en el archivo `Manifest`  (*`have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`*).  Por cierto, respeta la convención de nombres, las activity se escriben como los nombres de clase, con las primeras letras de cada palabra en mayúscula.

Comment: @ragnamex en el sitio ya puedes encontrar bastante información sobre este problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ActivityNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error dice que no encuentra la `Activity`, debido probablemente a que no ha sido declarada en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Conviene que abras ese archivo y revises si tienes agregada tu activity  `searchtabs`.

Debe haber algo como esto más o menos, y si no está, debes agregarlo:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.searchtabs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_searchtab"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="tu-paquete.activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Debes verificar todos los atributos tales como `label, parentActivityName` (si lo tiene), `theme` ... y el apartado `meta-data` si es que es una activity dependiente de otra. En todas esas partes debes poner datos **reales** de tu contexto.

Si tienes dudas sobre la estructura del `Manifest`, [puedes consultar la documentación de Android al respecto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=es-419).

> **NOTA SOBRE LA CONVENCIÓN DE NOMBRES:**
>
> Conviene que apliques las normas sobre la *convención de nombres* 
>   para hacer tu código legible para cualquier programador que lo deba
>   revisar o si en un futuro hay trabajo en colaboración con otros.
>
> La convención de nombres para activities es la misma que para las
>   clases: *la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula*, también, por
>   lo general, cuando es una `activity` se suele poner la palabra
>   `Activity` en el nombre. Respetando esas normas tu clase se debería
>   llamar: **`SearchTabsActivity`**.
>
> Esto no afecta el funcionamiento del código, pero sí a la claridad del
>   mismo.